# capture screenshot on failure selenium rc testNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, testng

I am using selenium to run my automated scripts which I prepare in Eclipse (Java) with TestNG framework . Can anybody help me on how to capture the screenshot of failure which can be stored and saved for future references.

Comment: @Slanec can u please look into it.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/testng-users/j3N228NPd0c. There are two or three implementations and it's commented by the TestNG creator himself.

Comment: I have done a good research, but still not able to solve the problem.If anyone who is using such a piece of code can provide me the working code.I use Selenium RC to run my scripts . I prepare my scripts in java using TestNG framework .

Comment: For folks using Web Driver, instead of RC, there's a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18654224/712526).

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to @AfterMethod (TestNG) annotation

```
@AfterMethod
public void closeBrowser(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    if (!result.isSuccess()) {

        File imageFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String failureImageFileName = result.getMethod().getMethodName()+ new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-ss").format(new GregorianCalendar().getTime())
                + ".png";
        File failureImageFile = new File(failureImageFileName);
        FileUtils.moveFile(imageFile, failureImageFile);
    }
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: @KingArasen Hi Arasan, Heartiest thanks for the solution you provided.When I implemented, it showed an error --- java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot
Can u please help me with this exception.

Comment: @VirendraJoshi Did you declare wedriver object (driver)?

Comment: @KingArasen No, I am using Selenium RC ..So I am working with Selenium class object.I am using Selenium object at place of driver.

Comment: you can try this project - https://github.com/yev/seleniumMvnScreenshot. Add this dependency in your POM. Add Listener for your selenium tests, and this plugin will do all for you.